# ¿Como puedo redondear un numero con floor en ruby con un decimal?, me sale error en la linea 24

Tags: ruby, redondeo

```
def numero_de_likes(likes)
    
    if likes < 1000
        "#{likes}"
        
        elsif likes < 1_000_000
            "#{(likes / 1000.to_f).floor(1)}K"
        
        else
            "#{(likes/1_000_000.to_f).floor(1)}M"
    
    end

end


p numero_de_likes(778)
p numero_de_likes(1000)
p numero_de_likes(1999)
p numero_de_likes(34_567)
p numero_de_likes(7_456_345)
```

Comment: Ni idea cual es la línea 24, pero ese código no me dio ningún error. Me retornó `"778"`, `"1.0K"`, `"1.9K"`, `"34.5K"` y `"7.4M"` respectivamente para c/u de las llamadas que pusiste al final

Comment: @AlterLagos en mi consola me sale: in `floor': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError), que programa usaste para hacerlo correr?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema debe ser que estás usando una versión de ruby menor a 2.4, donde [`.floor` no recibe parámetros](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-floor). Desde 2.4 que [puedes indicar](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-floor) la cantidad de decimales a retornar.

Tu opción es actualizar ruby y si no, considera el usar [`.round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-round), si es que aplica para tu problema el redondeo.

Answer (score -1):

Yo pude reproducir tu metodo sin problemas, igualmente lo realice con .round(1)

def numero_de_likes(likes)

```
if likes < 1000
    "#{likes}"
    elsif likes < 1_000_000
        "#{(likes / 1000.to_f).round(1)}K"
    else
        "#{(likes/1_000_000.to_f).round(1)}M"
end
```

end